# Using focus() within setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I try to change the focus for children of an element periodically. This [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WvLAx/1/)

```
<div id="test">
    <p>This is a test</p>
    <p>another test</p>
    <p>Thirs test</p>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
#test p {
    color:blue
}
#test p:active, #test p:focus {
    color:red;
}
```

and JavaScript

```
function test() {
    var el = document.getElementById("test"),
        nodes = el.getElementsByTagName("p"),
        j = nodes.length - 1,i=0;
    var id = setInterval(
    function () {
        nodes[i].focus();
        if (i == j) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }, 1000);
};
test();
```

but this simple example does not work. The problem is associated with `nodes[i].focus();`, as `nodes[i].style.color='red';` works.

I know that this approach is not perfect, and I appreciate any comment for improving the event.

Comment: Did you check the console? `test` doesn't exist on that fiddle.

Comment: He means this one: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'test' of object [object Object] is not a function `

Comment: @elclanrs sorry that was a typo when copying the codes. I updated the link.

Comment: It seems you're not clearing your interval btw.

Comment: @elclanrs then why `nodes[i].style.color='red';` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that paragraphs are not focusable by default, the active state is triggered with a click, but it's not the focus event. To make it work you just need to make those paragraphs focusable:

```
<div id="test">
<p tabindex=0>This is a test</p>
<p tabindex=0>another test</p>
<p tabindex=0>Thirs test</p>
```

Then you probably want to clear the interval at some point, or better yet, use `setTimeout` (unless you want this to run forever...) but that's a different issue. Here's a demo with your exact code but with focusable `p`:

http://jsfiddle.net/WvLAx/3/

Comment: Would an ascending tabindex not be preferable ?

Comment: @mplungjan: zero works as "auto", there's no need to add indices manually, unless you need it for layout purposes.

Comment: Cool. Noted. Never needed 0 before :)

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to solve your problem

```
var myInterval;
var interval_delay = 500;
var is_interval_running = false; //Optional

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).focus(function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval); // Clearing interval if for some reason it has not been cleared yet
        if  (!is_interval_running) //Optional
            myInterval = setInterval(interval_function, interval_delay);
    }).blur(function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval); // Clearing interval on window blur
        is_interval_running = false; //Optional
    });
});

interval_function = function () {
     is_interval_running = true; //Optional
     // Code running while window is in focus
}
```